# Stopping while waiting for user input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a game. In the game, the player and enemies are stored inside objects.
Each object has properties such as:

```
$player->health
$player->attack  (this is a value, as in attack power)
```

Then there's the php function which handles the fight:

```
function fight($player, $enemy) {...}
```

it uses functions like `attack($player, $enemy)` and `castSpell($player,$enemy)`.

Now, here is the problem: the game runs on a round system, the player and the enemy each has their turn. What I want is that every time it's the player's turn, the script will wait until the user clicks, and then a function is called according to the button pushed.

I was thinking of using Javascript setTimeout and then stopping it when the user clicks, but as all the objects and functions I use are in php.

How can I do this otherwise?

Comment: are you looking to call the server each time something happens? why not use events on the client to ajax the server?

Comment: you only get the information from the database (where php is involved) - use js for the game e.g. here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/ is a good tutorial

Comment: There are some good reasons to put game logic on the server such as preventing cheating and, in multiplayer, simplifying synchonisation.

Comment: Would it be a good solution, if every time the user makes an action I would convert the php objects from the databse to javascript, do what's to be done with javascript, and then convert them back to php and save them on the server?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot wait for user input in the middle of a PHP script: a PHP script runs, generates output (usually an HTML page), and then exits. The output is then sent to the user's browser, where they can read and interact with it.

The interaction you describe will require use of AJAX, so that the initial page is rendered and sent to the browser, and then `onclick` handlers or similar in the JS will cause extra calls to a PHP script which works out what should happen based on the event clicked. You will need to persist your objects, e.g. using `$_SESSION`, between the various PHP calls.

All AJAX really means is that the PHP script returns a small piece of data, rather than a whole page. So clicking "cast healing spell" might request "/ajax_fight_action.php?player=1&action=cast_spell&spell_name=healing" which would return (`echo`) an XML or JSON string that lets your JS know the new health of the player.

Answer (score 1):

To detect the end of a player's turn, bind event handlers to the buttons. In this handler, send the turn details to the server via ajax. The server will do it's thing and then return whatever it needs to. The 'success' method then needs to update the page accordingly and trigger the start of the next turn, repeating the process.

You could end up with javascript like this (using JQuery as cross-browser event handling and ajax quirks can be a bit of a nightmare).

```
$('.button').click(function()) {
  // here do what ever is appropriate to disable the buttons, so the player to wait until the game is ready for his next turn

  $.ajax({ 
    url: serverUrl,
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).attr('id'), // assumes the id of each button is the name of the action
    success: function(result) {
       // update the client based on the data returned by the server (result)

       // do whatever the game requires to start the next turn (e.g. re-enabling the buttons)
    }
  });
});
```

PHP is probably not the best server-side language to use as it throw up a number of issues as a result of the fact that scripts only survive for the lifetime of the request (i.e a turn). You need to work out how to preserve state on the server from one turn to the next. For a single player game you may be able to cram it all into the session variable, but for multiplayer (or multi session) games you will probably find yourself going down the database route. A language that allowed your scripts to live longer (e.g. python) might make your life a lot easier

Answer (score -1):

use php's sleep function that will stop the script for specified time such as sleep(4) will stop script for 4 seconds

Comment: PHP's `sleep` will not be able to *sleep until the user clicks a button in the browser*

Comment: ...just what I was looking for. Although it didn't answer the original question, it was valuable for me, thanks :-)